# add megamenu (containerwidth) in child of menu item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My menu has a container then `col-md-7` for the menu. 
This menu is a ul with li. In this li i need a megamenu dropdown that has the width and placement of the container.

[image]

If i place it out of the ul li i have some issues the hover.

The menu is sticky, so it has to be position

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="menu menu-container col-md-7 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 desktop">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="" href="http://wearhouse-dev.webshopapp.com/vans/">VANS<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="megamenu ">
                        <ul class="dropmenu">
                            <li><a href="http://wearhouse-dev.webshopapp.com/vans/old-skool/" class="animsition-link">OLD SKOOL</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://wearhouse-dev.webshopapp.com/vans/classics/" class="animsition-link">CLASSICS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://wearhouse-dev.webshopapp.com/vans/boots/" class="animsition-link">BOOTS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://wearhouse-dev.webshopapp.com/vans/atwood/" class="animsition-link">ATWOOD</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://wearhouse-dev.webshopapp.com/vans/iso-runners/" class="animsition-link">ISO RUNNERS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://wearhouse-dev.webshopapp.com/vans/sk8-hi/" class="animsition-link">SK8-HI</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://wearhouse-dev.webshopapp.com/vans/pro/" class="animsition-link">PRO</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- end row-->
</div>
<!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use [Yammm](http://%20[1]:%20http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/%22Yammm%22) Mega Menu.Mostly Use to Create Mega Menu and its easy to implement